# ERC721 balance call

Tags: erc-721

Is it possible to call the total balance that an ERC721 is holding? I am running a charitable minting Dapp and I would like to display the amount raised so far by displaying the total balance held by the contract.

I am fetching the total supply of tokens this way

```
export const fetchData = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchDataRequest());
    try {
      let totalSupply = await store
        .getState()
        .blockchain.smartContract.methods.totalSupply()
        .call();
      // let cost = await store
      //   .getState()
      //   .blockchain.smartContract.methods.cost()
      //   .call();

      dispatch(
        fetchDataSuccess({
          totalSupply,
          // cost,
        })
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      dispatch(fetchDataFailed("Could not load data from contract."));
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

unless you make the contracts ERC721 enumerable, I don't see how you can achieve this. Could we have a look at the contract ?

Comment: https://etherscan.io/address/0x899FFb968648827e577831b06A657C86f0fe97a7#code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).